# How do I save the toolbar ordering in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Every time I launch Eclipse I drag the toolbars to the order I want them. It never saves this. How do I permanently reorder my toolbar?

Comment: What version of Eclipse, and what toolbars in what order? (I have the Oxygen version)

Comment: 2019-06. I just want the debug icons on the far right and some other changes, maybe Tomcat to the left of that.

Comment: When I move the parts of the toolbar to another point, they keep the same place for me after restarting Eclipse. You did not say which Eclipse version that you have, but what perspective are you viewing for the toolbar changes?

Comment: The version is 2019-06, that's the new naming convention. The debug perspective won't remember toolbar changes.

Comment: Oh, did not realize the new naming convention. For my Oxygen version (it's old, I know), the debug perspective keeps the debug option at the far right of the other toolbar options after re-starting. I wonder if there is a preference setting or a new way to customize the toolbar in the newer versions? If I get a chance, likely won't be today though, I'll have to check it out.